# Creating a world shape file with rdal package

Tags: r, spatial, rgdal

I am trying to create a world shape file similar to London one. I am using this shape file. [Link to the shape file](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries). I have downloaded this file and I issue the command lnd@countries. I am getting the following error. Any suggestions?

```
library(rgdal)
lnd <- readOGR(dsn = "countries", layer = "ne_10m_admin_0_countries")
head(lnd@countries, n = 4)

 Error in head(lnd@countries) : 
   no slot of name "countries" for this object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
```

Comment: Is "countries" your working directory where "ne_10m_admin_0_countries" is located? If so, then you can plot a map of all countries using `plot(lnd)`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to get with `lnd@countries`. If you want the first 4 names of the countries, then try 'head(lnd@data$NAME, n=4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking the syntax... An OGR data object will have the data stored in myobject@data, and the coordinates in myobject@coords.

```
data = readOGR("/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/ne_10m_admin_0_countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp", "ne_10m_admin_0_countries")
colnames(data@data)
```

Note that there is no field named "countries", which is what you are asking for in your question:

```
 [1] "scalerank"  "featurecla" "LABELRANK"  "SOVEREIGNT" "SOV_A3"     "ADM0_DIF"   "LEVEL"      "TYPE"       "ADMIN"      "ADM0_A3"    "GEOU_DIF"  
[12] "GEOUNIT"    "GU_A3"      "SU_DIF"     "SUBUNIT"    "SU_A3"      "BRK_DIFF"   "NAME"       "NAME_LONG"  "BRK_A3"     "BRK_NAME"   "BRK_GROUP" 
[23] "ABBREV"     "POSTAL"     "FORMAL_EN"  "FORMAL_FR"  "NOTE_ADM0"  "NOTE_BRK"   "NAME_SORT"  "NAME_ALT"   "MAPCOLOR7"  "MAPCOLOR8"  "MAPCOLOR9" 
[34] "MAPCOLOR13" "POP_EST"    "GDP_MD_EST" "POP_YEAR"   "LASTCENSUS" "GDP_YEAR"   "ECONOMY"    "INCOME_GRP" "WIKIPEDIA"  "FIPS_10_"   "ISO_A2"    
[45] "ISO_A3"     "ISO_N3"     "UN_A3"      "WB_A2"      "WB_A3"      "WOE_ID"     "WOE_ID_EH"  "WOE_NOTE"   "ADM0_A3_IS" "ADM0_A3_US" "ADM0_A3_UN"
[56] "ADM0_A3_WB" "CONTINENT"  "REGION_UN"  "SUBREGION"  "REGION_WB"  "NAME_LEN"   "LONG_LEN"   "ABBREV_LEN" "TINY"       "HOMEPART"
```

To get the first four countries by name, noting that this depends on the order of features not the alphabetic order (which happens to match here):

```
head(data@data$NAME, 4)
```

Note that they were clever enough to include a `NAME_SORT` field for proper ordering (in English, presumably).